# CorelDraw VBA создание макросов

Tags: vba, corel-draw

Решил задать вопрос с надеждой, что кто-либо поможет. И так мне требуется создать макрос который бы поставил кропмарки. Сейчас застрял на моменте вычисления координат углов выделенного объекта. Хотелось узнать как такое реализовать, может кто-то имел дело с макросами в Coreldraw?

Comment: *Сейчас застрял на моменте вычисления координат углов выделенного объекта.* ЕМНИП в CDR нет выделенного объекта, есть только коллекция выделенных объектов, даже когда там один элемент, и её надо перебирать и искать нужный объект. Его координаты и размеры даст метод GetBoundingBox.

Comment: Будет что-то типа `For Each obj In ActiveSelectionRange : obj.GetBoundingBox xCoord, yCoord, xSize, ySize : Next`. Есссно переменные для приёма должны быть определены (As Double).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Извиняюсь за свою не точность.

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя такой набор функций накидал. Как они используются в основном проекте - выложить не могу, потому что там другое всякое задействовано. Но вот сами функции с примером. Основная функция drawBlock рисует прозрачный прямоугольник - контур реза, плюс метки вокруг (соответственно, размер надо задавать обрезной).

[tttest.bas](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BCyc%2FbnibwRqXk)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я уже справился со своей задачей, у меня все работает. Однако есть один несущественный недочет. Есть ли возможность после того как марки нарисуются их сгруппировать, чтобы они являлись одним объектом?